# What does it mean if a person says that he saw a 'Monster' eat his friends?

Tags: phrase-meaning

He didn't say 'Animal'. He specifically said that his friends were devoured by a 'Monster'. He submitted his story to Fate Magazine, which is about encounters with the paranormal. He was active on forums relating to encounters with the paranormal, and sent letters to paranormal investigators.

Source:

https://thoughtcatalog.com/christine-stockton/2021/12/a-florida-teen-said-a-sea-monster-killed-four-of-his-friends/

My question is, what does he mean by 'Monster'?

Comment: The linked article says *sea monster* several times, and even supplies drawings. What else is there to know? Oh, it was a *hungry* sea monster.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty - I am wondering what he means by the word 'monster'. He doesn't say 'sea animal' or 'sea creature'. He says 'monster'.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/monster

Comment: @Kate Bunting I'm guessing he was talking about an imaginary creature? He said something imaginary magically appeared in real life?

Comment: Well, he apparently claimed to have really seen it, but he said it was _like_ the monsters in stories.

Comment: So, he is saying he saw some magical/supernatural creature, not an animal?

Comment: The paranormal is full of things that are, well, **para**normal.

Comment: Yes, not an animal that is known to be real. Perhaps not magical, but something unknown to science.  A lion isn't a monster, nor is a whale.  But a long necked sea-lizard that eats people is a monster.  He says it was real, but you may think it is imaginary.

Comment: This is a drawing of what he claims to have seen: https://i.imgur.com/eNUukYGl.jpg

Comment: Please do not [cross-post your question on different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/295232).

Answer (score 1):

Monster from Merriam-Webster

```
an animal of strange or terrifying shape
a mythical monster
a sea monster
```

English speakers will commonly use the word "monster" for "strange or terrifying" animals or people.  And will also use the word for "extra large".  "Monsters of the Midway" was once a well-known expression to describe the American football team Chicago Bears and captured both meanings.

Etymology for "monster" from etymonline.com

> Abnormal or prodigious animals were regarded as signs or omens of impending evil. Extended by late 14c. to fabulous animals composed of parts of creatures (centaur, griffin, etc.). Meaning "animal of vast size" is from 1520s; sense of "person of inhuman cruelty or wickedness, person regarded with horror because of moral deformity" is from 1550s. As an adjective, "of extraordinary size," from 1837. In Old English, the monster Grendel was an aglæca, a word related to aglæc "calamity, terror, distress, oppression." Monster movie "movie featuring a monster as a leading element," is by 1958 (monster film is from 1941).